# Create a new Outlook profile through batch script?

Tags: batch-file

How to create a new outlook profile through a batch script ?

this would be used by different users to repair their outlook profile once the Profiles get corrupted.

Please help. Any suggestions good bad would be appreciated.

Thanks to you all.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, post what you have. If not, try something, and then post!

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).